# Añadir Menú contextual a OnLongClickListener

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo añadir a mi OnLongClickListener un menú contextual? Quiero que al pulsar sobre una ImageButton se abra el menú contextual, cómo puedo hacerlo de forma correcta?

Menú Contextual:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_accesorios, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.prueba_menu:
            Intent abc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nueva1.class);
            startActivity(abc);
            return true;
        case R.id.prueba1_menu:
            Intent def = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nueva2.class);
            startActivity(def);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

OnLongClickListener:

```
icon_cat_accesorios.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo conseguí solucionar, dejo aquí la solución para quien necesite algo parecido:

Añadimos:

```
registerForContextMenu(icon_cat_accesorios);
```

Finalmente no hay que usar *OnLongClickListener* para realizar la acción

Y modificamos el onCreateContextMenu:

```
@Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_accesorios, menu);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres al menú contextual que se abre en la esquina superior derecha, puedes abrirlo mediante [openContextMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu(android.view.View)) :

```
openContextMenu(view); // Abre menú creado en onCreateOptionsMenu()
```

> [openContextMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu(android.view.View)) Abre programáticamente el menú contextual desde
>   una vista en particular.

---

Ejemplo:

```
   //obtenemos la referencia del boton.
   final  Button btnOpenMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpenMenu);
    //Registramos el boton para poder abrir el menú contextual.
    registerForContextMenu(btnStop);

    //agregamos un listener para abrir el menú
    btnOpenMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            openContextMenu(btnOpenMenu); //llama el método onCreateContextMenu()

        }
    });



@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

}
```

Adicionalmente para anular el registro se realizaría de esta forma, sobre la vista que originalmente se registro para poder abrir el menú.

```
unregisterForContextMenu(btnOpenMenu);
```

Comment: Lo he añadido pero no funciona, el móvil vibra reconociendo que al pulsar esa ImageButton hay una acción pero no se me abre el menu contextual @Jorgesys quiero que al pulsar la ImageButton se abra el menú contextual encima, no en la esquina superior derecha, quizás ahí está el problema

Comment: Tienes la creación de tu menú en onCreateOptionsMenu() ?

Comment: Sí, arriba en al derecha si me sale, el problema es que no se abre el menu contextual al pulsar encima de la imagebutton, tengo que ir arriba a la derecha (no quiero que salga ahí, solo al pulsar encima de la imagebutton) @Jorgesys

Comment: equivoque el método es openContextMenu !!!!!

Comment: Nada! Gracias ! @Jorgesys , pásate por aquí si puedes que tiene algo que ver el tema, a ver si me puedes echar una mano: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46451/un-menucontextual-distinto-para-cada-imagebutton

Comment: es sencillo mediante el id de la vista que se registro, agrego respuesta.