# Un MenuContextual distinto para cada ImageButton

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo tener un menú contextual diferente para distintas ImageButton?
Por ejemplo, para ser concreta:

> Imagen 1 - Menú Contextual 1
>
> Imagen 2 - Menú Contextual 2
>
> ...

Así hago para tener un menú contextual en una ImageButton:

```
    registerForContextMenu(icon_cat_accesorios);

}
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_accesorios, menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.prueba1_menu:
                    Intent abc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba.class);
                    startActivity(abc);
                    return true;
                case R.id.prueba2_menu:
                    Intent def = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba.class);
                    startActivity(def);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso puedes crear otro menú (.xml) el cual sería abierto de acuerdo al boton que tu asignes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ambos botones deben estar registrados para abrir el menú contextual.

```
registerForContextMenu(imageButtonA);
registerForContextMenu(imageButtonB);
```

Al abrir el menú contextual (por medio de `onCreateContextMenu()` ) se determina el id del botón (vista) y el menú que abrirá el botón.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    if(v.getId() == R.id.ImageButtonA) { //Boton A abre menú definido en menu.xml
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.ImageButtonB) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu); //Boton B abre menú definido en menu2.xml
    }
}
```

Ahora para determinar que abriremos a partir de la opción del menú lo realizamos dentro de `onContextItemSelected()`

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.prueba1_menu:
            Intent abc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(abc);
            return true;
        case R.id.prueba2_menu:
             Intent def = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba.class);
             startActivity(def);
             return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es muy clara, pero tengo un problema, al pulsar sobre los item no se ejecuta la acción que en este caso sería ir a una activity, que tengo mal en mi código? @Jorgesys

Comment: Debes revisar que los id que ejecutan esa acción estén contenidos en el archivo .xml del menú, me refiero a R.id.prueba1_menu y R.id.prueba2_menu

Comment: Entiendo lo que comentas en onCreateOptionsMenu() se infla solo un menú pero en realidad requerimos validar ids de dos menus. Agrego esa parte

Comment: Te marco esto como solucionado, ya que has respondido perfectamente a mi pregunta y creo una nueva para intentar solucionar allí mejor este problema que te he comentado, pásate si puedes: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46457/los-items-de-men%C3%BA-contextual-no-realiza-la-acci%C3%B3n-al-pulsar-sobre-el

Comment: @UserNameYo ok de cualquier forma agregué aquí lo que comentas también para que sea de utilidad a otro usuario.