# Los item's de Menú Contextual no realiza la acción al pulsar sobre el

Tags: java, android

Cuando pulso en uno de los item's de mi menú contextual no hace nada, no realiza la acción que le asigno que en este caso sería ir a otra activity, qué error cometo? dejo mi código:

```
    registerForContextMenu(icon_cat_accesorios);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();


    if(v.getId() == R.id.icon_cat_accesorios) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_accesorios, menu);
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.prueba1_menu:
                Intent abc1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba1.class);
                startActivity(abc1);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba2_menu:
                Intent abc2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba2.class);
                startActivity(abc2);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba3_menu:
                Intent abc3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba3.class);
                startActivity(abc3);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba4_menu:
                Intent abc4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba4.class);
                startActivity(abc4);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba5_menu:
                Intent abc5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba5.class);
                startActivity(abc5);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="prueba"
        android:id="@+id/prueba1_menu" />
    <item android:title="pruebaaa"
        android:id="@+id/prueba2_menu" />
    <item android:title="pruebaaaa"
        android:id="@+id/prueba3_menu" />
    <item android:title="pruebaaaaaaa"
        android:id="@+id/prueba4_menu" />
    <item android:title="pruebaaaaaaaaaa"
        android:id="@+id/prueba5_menu" />
</menu>
```

Comment: El error es que no estás asignando a tu `switch` los `break` de los `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que la creación del menú se realizo dentro de `onCreateContextMenu()`, para determinar que elemento se selecciono del menú, lo realizamos dentro de [onContextItemSelected()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)) :

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

       switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.prueba1_menu:
                Intent abc1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba1.class);
                startActivity(abc1);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba2_menu:
                Intent abc2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba2.class);
                startActivity(abc2);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba3_menu:
                Intent abc3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba3.class);
                startActivity(abc3);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba4_menu:
                Intent abc4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba4.class);
                startActivity(abc4);
                return true;
            case R.id.prueba5_menu:
                Intent abc5 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), prueba5.class);
                startActivity(abc5);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Solucionado, gracias por toda tu ayuda! @Jorgesys

Comment: Un placer amigo, saludos. ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ